# MobaXterm - jump words with alt-f/b

Tags: mobaxterm

I'm using MobaXterm from Windows 10 to ssh into a linux box. I would like to use the alt-f and alt-b to move the cursor by words (emacs bindings), but this only works with the left alt key, not the right alt key. Doing this with the right alt key just types a 'f' or 'b' on the console, it behaves as if it weren't pressed.

It seems like this is a behavior of MobaXterm (v20.5, just downloaded) as the keys work as expected on Xterm. Also, right-alt + backspace deletes whole words for me in MobaXterm.

Has anyone seen this or know if there's a solution? I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap the right alt to the left alt key. Here is the script for that:

```
RAlt::LAlt
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted MobaXterm and it looks like this is indeed behavior that they see and it sounds like it isn't meant to be this way. Maybe (hopefully) this will get changed in a later update.

This was their response:

"Hello Daniel,
I am from the support team.
Thank you for reporting this behavior.
I managed to reproduce it on my side.
I will talk with the development team in order to see if we can improve this at a later release of MobaXterm.
Best regards.

Question:
The alt-f and alt-b seem to only work with the left alt, not with the right alt. The right alt combinations work with Xterm so I don't think it's a keyboard hardware issue.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there somewhere I can configure this to work?"